# Does anyone fund research in mathematical finance?

Tags: mathematics, funding, finance

The question is pretty much the title.  If you are an academic, is it possible to get anyone to pay you to do research in mathematical finance?

You can interpret the question broadly, to include mathematics or computational science that is used in finance, as long as this research has some real connection to finance as practiced today.

Comment: Funding research in topic X is not the same as having someone _pay_ you to do X, especially for academics who are paid by their institutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignoring the somewhat tendentious statements about mathematicians and funding mathematics, the [National Science Foundation](http://www.nsf.gov) in the US is one example of an agency funding research in mathematical finance. In fact, all I did was type "nsf mathematical finance" into google and I got three awards listed in the top 10. I'm sure there are many more.

Comment: thanks, I should have thought of that.  I had to Google "tendentious".

Answer (score 2):

[Man Group plc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_Group) does just that, particularly through the [Oxford-Man Institute of Quantitative Finance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford-Man_Institute_of_Quantitative_Finance). Further information can be accessed through the Institute's [website](http://www.oxford-man.ox.ac.uk), which also provides contact details.

Comment: You have enough rep to post more than one link. Please do so and also provide more info. Thanks.